# Match name within date range between to pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to solve this problem to merge two datasets based on player name and if it's within a date range. is it possible to do this with fuzzy matching? Tournaments can last for up to two weeks. I've been able to partial match some names with fuzzymatch but matching the names closest to the date is crucial. Is it possible to do this with fuzzy matching?

df1

```
tourney date, Player Name,
04-01-2018,    R. Nadal,
04-01-2018,    N. Djokovic,
04-01-2018,    R. Federer,
```

df2

```
Date,          Player Name,
05-01-2018,    Rafael Nadal,
06-01-2018,    Novak Djokovic,
07-01-2018,    Roger Federer,
```

Here's my code so far

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display , HTML
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/data1.csv' , 
encoding='latin-1')
df2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/data2.csv' , 
encoding='latin-1')


def match_name(name , list_names , min_score=70):
    max_score = 1
    max_name = ""
    for name2 in list_names:
        score = fuzz.ratio(name , name2)

        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name , max_score)


dict_list = []


for name in df1.Player_name:
    match = match_name(name , df2.Player_Name , 50)
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({"Runner_Name": name})
    dict_.update({"Player_Name": match[0]})
    dict_.update({"score": match[1]})
    dict_list.append(dict_)
 merge_table_ = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)

merge_table_
```

Comment: The library uses Levenshtein distance which compares two strings. In fact the library provides some more comparison functions in order to igonre word order etc. I'm not sure that is what you want to use. But that highly depends on your data. Are the players in dataframes 1 and 2 only and consistently distinguished by replacing the first name with an abbreviated form? Then I'd rather write a function that uses this knowledge and matches the two columns. In order to get the matching regarding dates I'd filter by date and calculate the time deltas and sort by them.Levenshtein can't be used here.